# InfoPath - Unsupported HTML attribute encountered: ‘lang’

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, rich-text

In SharePoint online, for one of the list’s rich text box field is rendering html code instead of html format.
When checked the Infopath, through designer checker, getting warnings as –“Unsupported HTML attribute encourtered: ‘lang’”. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the result in InfoPath form when you are adding html code in rich text box?

Comment: the ``lang`` attribute was only allowed on **all** elements in an HTML5 document, so I presume the document mode is not HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All.
Infopath warning and html content showing as code instead of rendering the format seems different issues. Infopath warning was present in older versions of the form. So, we are suspecting that some user would have change the column setting to simple text and changed it back to richtext. And this could have caused the column values to render the content differently.

We created a CSOM script to read the content from rich text box columns and decoded the html value recursively and added it back to list item. Also we re assigned the modified & modified columns so that, we persist the original values.